# Custom NSTabView with lefttab

Tags: cocoa, nstabview

[image: Make NSTabVIew like this]

I want to make a NSTabView like CleanMyMac or other application.

Comment: I don't think you are looking at NSTabview, but more likely a source list, which is view based NSOutlineView.

Comment: @Cory What about the Tweetbot macOS app? That appears to be using a NSTabBarViewController with a custom NSTabView??

Answer (score 0):

Never tried to customize `NSOutlineView` or `NSTableView` that heavily but I doubt it would get close enough to the custom (read: *non-standard*) behaviour you're looking for..

You can check for third party, Open Source controls that implement something similar. There are a couple of controls listed on [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls?page=1&platform_id=mac-os-x) that come pretty close.

Comment: Can you give me some "key word" to search?

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa Controls is good idea.
Maybe this is a nice starting point:

https://github.com/monyschuk/LITabControl